# Cannot find drive after installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

Installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my system.
Created a partition of 30GB for the OS and left the other 130 GB to store my data, pics and stuff.
Installation went fine , but now I cannot see my other drive ( 130 GB) 
I can see 130 GB free space on "disk utility", but it shows capacity of 30GB only
I don’tknow how to access the 130GB partition to transfer my data form a external hard drive.
Note: I have just Ubuntu installed on my system , no dual OS.

Comment: please upload gparted screenshot to `imgur.com` and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

- Open gparted and note the name of the 130GB drive,it will be like(/dev/sdxx).
- Run the below command to manually mount a partition or drive.

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdxx
  ```

In the above command replace `xx` with your 130GB partition's last letter and number.

- Once you executed the above command,your drive will be mounted in `/media`.